# Add new row to database table from Datagrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

I am trying to update a database table from my datagrid using an event handler and ItemCommand. I manage to call the routine and everything is working fine except the text that is inserted into my database is empty. I managed to track this back to the text not being passed from my datagrids footer to the sql parameters. I tried using a string first and then passing that to the parameters but they were also empty. I am accessing the control using the following line.

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@GoodsDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CType(e.Item.FindControl("txtGoodsDesc"), TextBox).Text
```

The control itself is defined using

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Goods Descriptions">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblGoodsDesc" Text='<%# Eval("GoodsDesc") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtGoodsDesc" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3"></asp:TextBox>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Am I missing something here? It's like the text in the footer isnt being tied to the control before I call it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. I have worked out that the program is calling Page_Load when I click on the link to add the row, so the text boxes are actually being emptied before it tries to add them. I wasnt aware that Page_Load would be called first. I have a couple of ideas on how I might fix this, now I just have to hope I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So essentially I discovered that the issue that was occurring was that VB.Net was calling Page_Load before the event itself was being called, and in the Page_Load method I was calling the method that filled the datagrid, which cleared the textboxes in the footer before the values in them were being read.

To stop this I placed a condition around the call to the method in Page_Load

```
If Not IsPostBack Then

    FillDataGrid()

End If
```

Then I called the FillDataGrid() function as the very last step in the handler, meaning that the data was read in and then the datagrid was bound to the new values.

Answer (score 0):

HI Ryan, we will need more code then just that.  Where are you .Add +ing this parameter in addition where is e.Item.FindControl what event is it?

You need to check if you are on the footer control:

```
protected void dg_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
        {
            if (dg.EditItemIndex != -1)
            {
                ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtGoodsDesc")).Text
            }
        }
    }
```

Or in vb.net

```
if (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Footer) then
  Dim s as String=String.Empty
  s=CType(e.Item.FindControl("txtGoodsDesc"), TextBox).Text
end if
```